# Plot tick level control

Tags: r, plot, axis, axis-labels

Here is my question:

```
myd <- data.frame (V1 = paste ("V", 1:1000), V2 = rnorm(1000))

plot(myd[,1], myd[,2])
```

[image]

As my plot is busy in axis, I want to just put tick markers at every 100 and display corresponding labels. Also tick only (without label) is displayed at between two hundred ticks. For example, ticks and labels at 1, 100, 200, 300.....1000, ticks only at 50, 150, 250, 350 ......950

How I can I achieve this ?

Edit:

Example :

```
|   |    |    |    |     |    |
V1       V100      V200      V300
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
plot(myd[,1], myd[,2], xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=seq(0,1000,50))
```

also have a look at `?axis` for details about ticks and labels.

### Updated answer

```
axis(1, at=seq(0,1000,100), label=paste0("V", seq(0, 1000, 100)))
axis(1, at=seq(50,1000,100), label=F, tick=T)
```

Comment: thanks your for the solution, still I seeking way to label on (V1..V100 at every hundred and no label tick only at every 50 in between two..

Comment: great ! the only issue I might need to resolve is label=paste0("V", seq(0, 1000, 100)), which is not automated solution as in real sense the names might be not series ...just created for sake of creating dummy data...